# Passing Jquery value to thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, thymeleaf

I have a Jquery code like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#viewModal').on('show.bs.modal',function(e){
        $('.row-select input:checked').each(function() {
            var i = $(this).closest("tr").index()-1;
            alert(i);
        })
    })
})
```

and I have program which use thymeleaf like this :

```
<label th:each="dataBarangModel:${ListDataBarangModel[i].kodeBarang}" th:text="${dataBarangModel}"></label>
```

How to pass value  in variable i in jquery code to variable i in thymeleaf code ?

Comment: Thymeleaf works on the server and parses your template into HTML code. When the page loaded into the browser your JavaScript function will be working with regular HTML; at this time Thymeleaf already has done.

Comment: can you give me example ?